# Returning php associative array from function to ajax call with json_encode() not and object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first post so i apologize if i leave something out or don't explain myself very well. All this code is in the same php file

My ajax call

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.href,
    data: {func: 'genString'},
    datatype: 'json'
})
.done(function ( response )
{
    console.log( response );
    console.log( repose.string );
});
```

Which falls into an if statement on the page

```
if ( isset ($_POST['func'] && $_POST['func'] == 'genString')
{
     exit(json_encode(myFunction()));
}
```

The function run on the page

```
function myFunction()
{
    /* Would generate a string based on the database */
    $arr = array('rows' => 1, 'string' => 'My test string');
    // Changes values in the array depending on the database
    return $arr;
}
```

This function is run to generate the array when the page itself is loaded and use the string portion to display the it and the rows part to set the height of a text area in the browser however when the ajax is called 
`console.log(respose)` this logs
`{"rows":1,"string":"My test string"}` instead of an object

However when i try logging or using the string 
`console.log( response.string );`
it shows up as undefined

I have done this previously and it has worked and returned an object which i can use in js with `response.string`. I have tried to use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT this had no effect on the result

Comment: You have a typo in `repose.string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the response is just being treated as a string (datatype). That's why `response.string` isn't working.

You can just tell by adding this:

```
console.log( typeof response );
```

So don't forget to put:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Inside you `if` block:

And you have a typo on the `if` block (isset and `response`):

```
if ( isset ($_POST['func']) && $_POST['func'] === 'genString' ) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode(myFunction()));
}
```

On the JS typo also:

```
console.log( response.string );
               ^^
```

Comment: Thanks the header fixed it the grammar errors were only from me typing it . I never knew of typeof in js thanks

Comment: @Dustin sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a grammatical errors.
The request option

```
datatype: 'json'
```

should be

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Thanks that is something I've overlooked